# How to provide Activity Context via Dagger 2 in an Android project?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

This is the code I have in my Activity.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_work_order)
        DaggerWorkOrderComponent.factory()
                .create(activity)
                .inject(activity)
}
```

This is my module.

```
@Module
object WorkOrderModule {

    private lateinit var context: Context

    fun setWorkOrderActivityContext(ctx: Context) {
        context = ctx
    }

    @Provides
    @JvmStatic
    fun provideContext(): Context = context

    @Provides
    @JvmStatic
    fun provideLogger(): Logger = getLogger()

    @Provides
    @JvmStatic
    fun provideAppDataManager(): AppDataManager = getAppDataManager()

    @Provides
    @JvmStatic
    fun provideFirebaseManager(): FirebaseManager = getFirebaseManager()

    @Provides
    @JvmStatic
    fun provideViewModel(
        logger: Logger,
        appDataManager: AppDataManager,
        firebaseManager: FirebaseManager
    ): WorkOrderVM = WorkOrderVM(context, logger, appDataManager, firebaseManager) // <=== line 45
}
```

and finally, this is my component.
@FeatureScope

```
@Component(modules = [WorkOrderModule::class])
interface WorkOrderComponent {

    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(@BindsInstance context: Context): WorkOrderComponent
    }

    fun inject(activity: WorkOrderActivity)
}
```

The application crashes and this is what I get:

> Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit
>   property context has not been initialized
>           at com.atco.forsite.screens.inspection.workOrder.di.WorkOrderModule.provideViewModel(WorkOrderModule.kt:45)

The line 45 has marked in the Module.

Comment: You are not initializing the WorkOrderModule in your activity because of which the context is coming null. Check this : https://www.raywenderlich.com/262-dependency-injection-in-android-with-dagger-2-and-kotlin

Comment: `object { var activity: Activity` is called a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

Provide `Context` as a *Dagger* module constructor parameter:

```
@Module
class WorkOrderModule constructor(private val context: Context)
```

Here both `lateinit var context` and `fun setWorkOrderActivityContext(ctx: Context)` are no longer needed.

Then in `Activity`'s `onCreate()` set the module to component:

```
DaggerWorkOrderComponent
    .builder()
    .module(
        WorkOrderModule(this)
    )
    .build()
    .inject(this)
```

In this case `interface Factory` isn't needed too.